# Gridbaglayout Second row scrolls out of the container

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am trying to achieve a layout similar to that of a carousel. It needs to have images added horizontally with a checkbox field in the second row. I have a panel within a jscrollpane and individual images are added to the panel as labels. Please see screen shot. When I scroll the pane , the first row containing the images stays well within the panel..but if you notice the second row of checkboxes , it scrolls out of the panel. Here is the code ...

```
for (int ii=0; ii<imageFiles.length; ii++) {
       GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();  
        lab1 = new FittoSize().getContents(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\images\\"+imageFiles[ii])));

        constraint.gridx = ii;
        constraint.gridy =0;  
        jPanel9.add(lab1,constraint);
    }
    for (int ii=0; ii<imageFiles.length; ii++) {
        GridBagConstraints constraint1 = new GridBagConstraints();         
        constraint1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;           
        chkbox = new Checkbox("asdasdada");
        constraint1.gridx = ii;
        constraint1.gridy =1;

        jPanel9.add(chkbox, constraint1);
      }
```

Not sure what is wrong..Any help is much appreciated..Thanks..

Comment: For better help sooner, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @StanislavL or the other way round (this seems to be older) Anyway, voting to close ...